# choose which subplot in matplotlib to plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm writing a function to show a summary of top 10 value counts values for each column in a given dataframe.

say we have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 4, 5, 6],
                   'b':[2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 5, 6],
                   'c':[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6]})
```

I want to be able to count the columns, and create a sized grid of plots which

I've created using tuples and finding the correct selection of square grid:

```
l = len(df.columns)
tups = [(z, z, z**2) for z in range(1, 10)]
param = tups[min([i for i, x in enumerate([l <= tup[2] for tup in tups]) if x])]
```

now I create the subplots:

```
for i in range(1, l+1):
    plt.subplot(param[0], param[1], i)
```

The difficulty I'm having is that I want to plot each of these for each subplot but when I iterate through, it just sets each one to the last grid plot, leaving the other ones blank.

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col].value_counts()[:10].plot('bar')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has most certainly been answered elsewhere already, but because of reasons I might just type here again.

```
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    ax = plt.subplot(param[0],param[1],i+1)
    df[col].value_counts()[:10].plot('bar', ax=ax)
```